# Is Common Trading Done? Robots to Rule Them All?

Tags: stocks, investing, technical-analysis

I'm a computer programmer and I've been processing the SEC filings. I've been building models and trying to automate building them out. However, I can not be the only one doing this. As it turns out, doing some research, a lot of people are doing this, with high frequency training and AI. This leads me with some concerns about the everyday investor, and can/should they compete with this technology? Also, I'm really new to trading actively (paper traded when I was 16 to 18, But that's not real experience), but anyone who's been doing this for their life notice any changes?

Comment: Investors are not traders.  Investors - at least successful ones - buy and hold for the long term.  There's really little advantage I can see for an AI in that situation.  But if there is, I expect Vanguard, TRP, Fidelity, or whatever company(s) I have my mutual funds with will be able to afford top-level ones to do their trading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think people can come close to automated trading, except for floor traders.  I believe floor traders can still outperform.  Computers don't get tired and they don't forget.

As for investors, that is a very different creature.  I do believe humans can outperform machines in investing in stocks and bonds.  Trading is investing in liquidity and acting a liquidity provider or a sink for excess liquidity.  I don't think Watson is there yet, although I have a project that I would like to build that would bump us way past Watson.  However, I am busy at the moment and that requires more time and effort than I have currently.  In fact, I am nearly certain I could bump a machine way past Watson.  Still, that is another day.  For the moment, I am sure humans win.

Comment: As someone who had worked with Watson, I think it is a glorified search engine. I hope they have updated it since I used its api. But I was highly disappointed in the results and "reasoning" it's indexing came up with.

Comment: Yes, but it can do some amazing things.  It doesn't reason, but most don't either.